# Why is Razor Template not displaying in Tridion (after installing it)?

Tags: tridion, razor-mediator

I have installed Razor mediator 1.2 at Tridion server and that server also having .NET 4.0.

I have restarted all service as they has suggested in the Razor-mediator docs.

After installing, the RazorTemplate option is not displaying in the TemplateType dropdown, when we try to create a new TBB.

Any ideas on why RazorTemplate option is not showing in Tridion?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "Why its not display razor option in Tridion?" All you will normally see is a new template building block type, and the TBBs will be visible in the Template Builder. What are you not seeing?

Comment: Thanks to all. Actually, i had missed to re-start the COM+ service.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

- If you have correctly followed all steps, you should try clearing
  your browser's cache. It often does the trick on these cases.
- If still not working, you may check the
  `Tridion.ContentManager.config`, and search for any reference to
  razor. If you can't find any, it means that the installer didn't work
  correctly. (Maybe execute again with admin privileges)
- Make sure you are creating a TBB and not a Component Template. Razor Templates are Tbb's

Comment: I have also crossed verify in the Tridion.Contentmanager.config file, its having razor references. yes, of course  i am creating a TBB and find that option there

Answer (score 2):

Check your Tridion config file `Tridion.ContentManager.config` for the following, assuming the Installer installed successfully. You could verify this from GAC assembly and also double check the PublicKeyToken with the config as well.

**Mediators Section:**

```
<mediators>
...
<mediator matchMIMEType="text/x-tcm-cshtml" type="Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.RazorMediator, Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5eeceedb34d9dfd7" />

</mediators>
```

**Config Sections:**

```
<configSections>
.....
<section name="razor.mediator" type="Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.Configuration.RazorMediatorConfigurationSection, Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5eeceedb34d9dfd7" />
...
</configSections>
```

**Template Types:**

```
<templateTypes>
..
      <add id="8" name="RazorTemplate" mimeType="text/x-tcm-cshtml" hasBinaryContent="false" contentHandler="Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.RazorContentHandler, Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5eeceedb34d9dfd7">
    <webDavFileExtensions>
      <add itemType="TemplateBuildingBlock" fileExtension="cshtml" />
    </webDavFileExtensions>
     </add>
</templateTypes>
```

If you have all the configuration correct, then this could be just caching of the UI.

You can force the clear cache by updating the `modification` count in `System.config` (web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration) .. `8` is just the number on my cms, this could be different for your CMS.

```
<server version="6.1.0.55920" modification="8">
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please check that you are looking COM+ at right place see Screenshots ---

Wrong :-![Wrong Place][1]

[image: Right Place]
Right:- ![]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try reinstalling again.

Comment: I have already done it and also checked in the tridion config file, its display the razor tag there. but still not display in TBB option