# I am getting error: 8000401a while logging to Tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am getting the following error, while logging in to Tridion. Could you please help me.

```
Error: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {9926D1CF-F158-418F-A9A2-B653B497D982} failed due to the following error: 
8000401a The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. 
Check the username and password. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000401A).

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000401A): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {9926D1CF-F158-418F-A9A2-B653B497D982} failed due to the following error: 
8000401a The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. 
Check the username and password. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000401A). 
at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54.TDSEWrapper.get_TDSE() 
at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54.TcmAuthorizationModule.context_AuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be your system user(MTSuser by default) got locked.

Could you please check the Identity properties of the Tridion Content Manager COM+ application and try again to login with this user.

Comment: Thanks for replying. How to check the Identity properties of the Tridion Content Manager COM+ application?

Comment: From the Windows Control Panel, access Administrative Tools and Component Services. The Component Services window opens. now Component Services > Computers > My Computer >COM+ application . now right click on tridion specific COM+ package , you will get identity tab. you can refer screen shot in my  this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727567/why-is-razor-template-not-displaying-in-tridion-after-installing-it/12729982#12729982

Comment: In identity tab, I retyped the password, just to ensure the correct password and restarted the Tridion Content Manager COM+ application and it worked. Thanks Ram.

Answer (score 1):

The identity of the user running the Tridion Content Manager COM+ application is correct. Check if the user exists and the password is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the COM service on CMS Server or reboot the CMS Server(which will automatically restart the service). 
Thanks

Comment: I have restarted the server but no luck.

Comment: No luck on this one..